# What is meant by "web apps should be naturally stateless like HTTP"?

Tags: http, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have read something along the lines of the following a fair few times when reading about Java EE web apps (and web apps in general) -

> Web apps should be naturally stateless like HTTP

1. Is this, in effect, saying that state should be pulled from the DB on every request and no information should be retained on the server between requests?
2. What is so bad about web apps being stateful? What disadvantages does it bring?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes.
2. It makes them more complex, because since multiple concurrent users modify the same state, making the app stateful quickly leads to stale or inconsistent data in memory. It also makes the app less scalable, because state consumes memory, and state must be replicated (or made available somehow) on all the web servers of the cluster.

Comment: But web-apps can't be 100% stateless (as in they will be 99.999% statelss) in that they at least have to store an identifier for the user in a session object? Is that correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. Play framework stores the ID in an encrypted cookie, for example. But yes, most of the time, the user ID is at least stored in a HTTP session. The more stateless, the best it is. If the session is very light, storing it in database doesn't cause much problem, for example, making the app stateless again.